# How to check if a certain certificate is already present in a keyvault?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault, azure-cli

In a nightly Azure pipelines build I have 2 tasks:

- First I delete and purge a self-signed certificate from a keyvault
- Then I import the same self-signed certificate into the keyvault

The reason I do it is to ensure that there is a certain certificate *always* is available in the keyvault.

Here is my current code:

```
# purge the self-signed cert from the Keyvault to avoid conflict; ignore failures
- task: AzureCLI@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    continueOnError: true
    failOnStandardError: false
    powerShellErrorActionPreference: 'silentlyContinue'
    inlineScript: |
      az keyvault certificate delete --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/certificates/my-self-signed-cert'
      az keyvault certificate purge --vault-name $(KeyVaultName) --id 'https://$(KeyVaultName).vault.azure.net/deletedcertificates/my-self-signed-cert'

# import the self-signed certificate my-self-signed-cert into the Keyvault
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: '${{ parameters.ArmConnection }}'
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    azurePowerShellVersion: '3.1.0'
    Inline: |
      $Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword' -Force -AsPlainText
      $Base64 = 'MIIKqQ____3000_CHARS_HERE______1ICAgfQ=='
      Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $(KeyVaultName) -Name my-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64 -Password $Pwd
```

My question is:

How could I please check if the certificate is maybe already available in the keyvault?

(Because I use ARM templates and the resources keep running and are not deleted, while the pipeline is being run every evening).

And if the certificate is there, how to skip the above 2 tasks (Azure-cli and the PowerShell)?

I don't quite understand how to use conditionals in the pipelines YAML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YAML cannot contain conditionals, so what you need to do is to handle the logic inside your powershell scripts.

There is a command for checking if the a given certificate is present in the vault, so how about doing something like this?

```
        $cert = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName "ContosoKV01" -Name "TestCert01"

        if(!$cert) {
          $Pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'MyPassword' -Force -AsPlainText
          $Base64 = 'MIIKqQ____3000_CHARS_HERE______1ICAgfQ=='
          Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $(KeyVaultName) -Name my-self-signed-cert -CertificateString $Base64 -Password $Pwd
        }
```

If you for some reason also want the delete and purge og certs you can do that in PowerShell aswell. Not sure why you use both CLI and plain PowerShell in your current setup?

Comment: Thanks! I have to use "az keyvault certificate purge", because there is no purge command in PowerShell. And if I just [Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Az.KeyVault/Remove-AzKeyVaultCertificate?view=azps-4.1.0) (without subsequent purging) and then try `Import-AzKeyVaultCertificate` - the latter command will fail.

Comment: You can purge like this: `Remove-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName 'Contoso' -Name 'MyCert' -InRemovedState`